# os.startfile() not opening .docx file

Tags: python

I am simply trying to open a `.docx` file, which is stored in the server shared area.

I have tried the following:

```
        notesPath = '//SERVER/shared_data/FolderOne/notes.docx'
        os.chdir('//SERVER/shared_data')
        os.startfile(notesPath)
```

With the `os.chdir` I am changing the path for command prompt, as I believe thats the issue. Becasue when I call `os.getcwd()` it returns me `C:\\Users\\Userone\\Desktop\\`. Thats what I though it was good idea to use os.chdir, convert it to //server and go from there.

But when I change the os.chdir in my code, the chdir is set to:

```
'\\\\SERVER\\shared_data'
```

with too many slashes

How can I resolve this issue?

**Traceback:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Userone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Userone\Desktop\project\Main App.py", line 293, in noteopen
    os.startfile(notesPath)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '//SERVER/shared_data/FolderOne/notes.docx'
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `chdir`. In which line does the error come up? Could you provide us with a full traceback?

Comment: Try removing // in front of the notesPath, and you do not need to change directort since you are giving absolute path (if it is in fact an absolute path) of the file.

Comment: updated the question with traceback, the file path I got from is the excel sheet, then clicked file I have the option to copy path, that way I validate the correct path

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, by open, I mean fully open the .docx file. Actually open the document itself

Comment: @PEmal What is the result when you check if the file even exist or not with os.path.isfile(notesPath) ?

Comment: The output for os.path.islfile is False

Comment: BTW, with `'\\\\SERVER\\shared_data'` you see the _representation_ of the string. Try `print('\\\\SERVER\\shared_data')` and you'll see the real content.

Comment: @PEmal UNC paths use backslashes. Use `r'\\SERVER\shared_data\FolderOne\notes.docx'` or `'\\\\SERVER\\shared_data\\FolderOne\\notes.docx'`

Comment: even with backslashes it comes up with ` The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: @Pemal can you navigate to that folder with Windows Explorer? You won't be able to read the file if you have no permission to the folder, even if it exists. If you don't have even `Read` permissions or `List Directory` on the folder, you won't even see the file

Comment: one second @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's a UNC path, just use a raw string and use back slashes. There should be no need to change the current directory.

```
notes_path = r'\\SERVER\shared_data\FolderOne\notes.docx'
os.startfile(notes_path)
```

Comment: `The system cannot find the file specified` it's so strange, the path exists. Also, when I type the path into file explorer, it does not recognize it too. the file is stored in network drive, does that help?

Comment: @Pemal `when I type the path into file explorer, it does not recognize it too.` then it doesn't exist or you don't have permission to read from that shared folder. Can you navigate to that server, that shared folder?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, I can navigate to it and open the .docx file manually, but, thtough python, its a no for some reason. Should I contact the administrator for anything specific?

Comment: @PEmal you just said `when I type the path into file explorer, it does not recognize it too.` How did you navigate there then? If you hit F4 when inside that folder, what path do you get? Perhaps you mistyped something?

Comment: What I mean by navigate is, through file explorer. And you mentioned '@Pemal can you navigate to that folder with Windows Explorer?' I though you meant through windows explorer, like google chrome or something.

Comment: Okay, so manually open the .docx file. Assuming you're using Microsoft Word, click *File*, and below the *Info* header it will have the file path. Left click on it, and select *Copy link to clipboard*. Copy that into Python. There's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos youre a genius

Comment: @PEmal or I have the same problem each time I try to find an file's path on my machine. Especially those installed by package managers like chocolatey.

Answer (score 0):

**file_path :- find your application or other file path. put as it is.**

*file_path = r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE'*

os.startfile(file_paht)

[copy of the application path and pest it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3ezs.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).